# Unicode NSIS Exec/ExecWait

Tags: nsis

Is it possible to execute command within Unicode NSIS script.
Execution works ok, if i use non Unicode NSIS version, but
when i try it with Unicode version it just doest do anything.

Command: Exec '"$TEMP/myFile.exe"'

Thank you

Comment: Unicode/ansi version should not matter with something like this

Comment: Yes you are right. I had problem with administrative privileges. The program i wanted to execute needed it, and when i was executing file, i got no answer back.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround.
I used UAC plugin (Unicode version) and executed

```
!insertmacro UAC_AsUser_ExecShell "$TEMP\myFile.exe"
```